# Uniform convergence of subsequence of function

Tags: real-analysis

I have this exercise:
Let $f_n:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}, n\in\mathbb{N}$ a sequence of continuous functions that punctualy converge to $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$.
I have to prove that if there exists a sequence in $\mathbb{R}$ ,$(r_n)$, such that $(r_n)\to r$ but $f_n(r_n)\not\to f(r)$ then $(f_n)$ does not converge uniformly to $f$ in $\mathbb{R}$.

Any hints would be great.

Comment: Assume that $(f_n)$ does converge uniformly and try proving that $f_n(r_n)\to f(r)$. Can you bound $|f_n(r_n)-f(r)|$ using the triangle inequality?

Answer (score 1):

Assume $(f_n)$ converges uniformly to $f$. We'll prove that $f_n(r_n)\to f(r)$.

Given $\epsilon>0$, use uniform convergence to find an $m$ such that $|f_m(x)-f(x)|<\epsilon$ for all $x$, for all $n\ge m$. Then use the continuity of $f_m$ to show that for sufficiently large $n$, we have $|f_m(r_n)-f_m(r)|<\epsilon$.

Applying the triangle inequality along the path $f(r)\to f_m(r)\to f_m(r_n)\to f(r_n)\to f_n(r_n)$, we see that for sufficiently large $n$, $|f(r)-f_n(r_n)|<4\epsilon$.

Answer (score 0):

Assume $\{f_n\} \longrightarrow f$ uniformly. Then $f$ is continuous, and using triangle inequality,

\begin{eqnarray*}
|f_n(r_n)-f(r)| & \leq & |f_n(r_n)-f(r_n)|+|f(r_n)-f(r)|\\
 & \leq & \sup_{x\in \mathbb{R}}|f_n(x)-f(x)|+|f(r_n)-f(r)|
\end{eqnarray*}
Now take $n \longrightarrow \infty$.

Comment: Nice, this is what I had in mind with my original comment. My answer essentially adds to this the proof that $f$ is continuous.

Comment: Thanks. And I like how you describe the development of your triangle inequality along a path.

Comment: hmm i´m sorry for asking but i don´t see how you get to a contradixtion when n goes infinity

Comment: Sine $\{f_n\} \rightarrow f$ uniformly we have $\sup_{x\in \mathbb{R}}|f_n(x)-f(x)|\rightarrow 0$. Moreover, since $f$ is continuous and $\{r_n\} \rightarrow r$ we have $\{f(r_n)\}\rightarrow r$. So the right hand side approaches zero and $$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}|f_n(r_n)-f(r)|\leq 0$$

Comment: ohhh i get it, and also one more question ${f(r_{n})}\longrightarrow{f(r)}$. thanks for answering